# Change a field option in the inherited class

Tags: python, django, django-models

For example, I have a code:

```py
from django.db import models


class AbstractClass(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=True)
    
    
class A(AbstractClass):
    field = models.CharField()
    
    
class B(AbstractClass):
    another_field = models.CharField()
    # and also for exmaple i need to set max_length 155 for the name field here
```

Can I somehow change a field option `max_length` of a field `name` in `AbstractClass`?

I searched through some sites, but, unfortunately, didn't find anything. I saw about `get_initial()` and `self.fields`, but I don't know how to imply it to the class and I am not sure if it is even suitable for my situation.

Answer (score 0):

You can overwrite the `name` field to change `max_length`

```
class B(AbstractClass):
    another_field = models.CharField()
    name = models.CharField(max_length=155, null=True)
```